# How do I automatically ignore empty cells (and adjust their role in a later function) in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Let's say I have a pair of four data points:

```
A   B   C   D
90  80  70  60
90  90      90
```

In column E, I hope to have a function, something like:

```
=((A1*4)+(B1*3)+(C1*2)+(D1))/10
```

How can I adjust this formula so that, if there is ever an empty cell, the formula automatically removes that cell from the formula? In doing so, *this should change the denominator of the final formula*; if C is an empty cell, I want to divide the entire formula by 8, not by 10 (since C is counted twice in the ultimate 10-count of the formula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `SUMPRODUCT` may used for.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:D1,{4,3,2,1})
```

will calculate `A1*4+B1*3+C1*2+D1*1` and if either `A1`, `B1`, `C1` or `D1` is blank this leads to `0` in `0*n` then.

And in

```
=SUMPRODUCT(NOT(ISBLANK(A1:D1)),{4,3,2,1})
```

the `NOT(ISBLANK(A1:D1)` leads to `{1,1,1,1}` if  `A1`, `B1`, `C1` and `D1` are not blank or it leads to `{1,1,0,1}` if `C1` is blank. So the formula leads to `10` (`4+3+2+1`) if all are not blank and to `8` (`4+3+0+1`)  if  `C1` is blank.

Putting it all together:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:D1,{4,3,2,1})/SUMPRODUCT(NOT(ISBLANK(A1:D1)),{4,3,2,1})
```